# Knowing the status of a form POST that is protected by X-Frame-Options

Tags: http, google-chrome, post, x-frame-options

I am going to describe my specific case below, but this might be useful to a number of web-mashups.

My web application POSTs to Twitter by filling a form and then submitting it (via javascript). The `target` of the form is set to an `iframe` which has an `onload` trigger. When the `onload` trigger is called the application knows that the POST was completed.

This used to work fine until Chrome version 11, which now respects the `X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN` sent by Twitter in the POST response. The POST goes through, but the `iframe's onload` is not called anymore.

It still works in Firefox 4, but I suppose that's a bug that will eventually get fixed.

Is there any other way to know the status of the POST? I understand that knowing the *contents* of the POST response would violate the security policy, but I am not interested in the contents. I would just like the app to be notified when the POST is completed.

Comment: Could you use AJAX for the submission instead of an iframe? Or do you not control the contents of the form itself?

Comment: @kpozon This is a cross-domain request, not possible without an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to know when the POST was submitted, and not necessarily whether it succeeded or not, you could poll the iframe's `contentWindow` and `contentWindow.document` on an interval. When you can no longer access one of those objects, or when the document has an empty body, that means that the iframe has loaded a page with `X-Frame-Options` restrictions, which likely means that the submission went through. It's hacky, but it looks like it will work for this purpose. (You'll probably have to go through a few combinations to figure out what the contents of restricted iframes look like in your target browsers.)

Comment: Will try this, but like you said, it is hacky. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by getting the headers of the page. In php it will be looks like,

`$url = 'http://www.google.com';

    print_r(get_headers($url));`

Comment: I am looking for browser side solutions. Cross-domain restrictions usually don't apply on the server side.